# 1990s(?) Japanese anime - People with eyes tattooed on their arms transform into robots "By the power of The Eye!"

Tags: story-identification, anime

I have been looking for an anime for about 15 years. I originally watched it on a French channel called "[Mangas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mangas_(TV_channel))". the anime itself probably dates from between 1980-2000.

The anime had similar points with Saint Seya, namely that a team of heroes would wear (or more like transform) into robots / armored fighter. There were around a dozen characters each with a specific transformation, among which one had parrot-like armor with green and orange feather-like scales.

The most important clue I can remember is that all those transforming characters had an eye tattoo on their forearm (right forearm I think, usually covered up in bandages) which would open as the character was say something along the lines of

> "*By the power of the eye*" ("*Par le pouvoir de l'oeil*" in the French version).

Comment: I've taken the liberty of cleaning up the spelling and grammar and trying to make the title a little more punchy.

Comment: Sure. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10):

I am the original poster but I lost my credentials so I am using another account.

Anyway, I finally found the said anime. It was *[Reideen the Superior](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=feH1hQoNFe4)* !

> A 38 episode remake aired as Raideen the Superior (超者ライディーン; Chōja Raidīn) in 1996. This series was directed by Toshifumi Kawase. Five seemingly ordinary teenagers are actually superheroes called "Raideens" and their mission is to fight their enemy the so-called "Super Devils." This series was notably different than the original, more akin to a Super Sentai series or Tekkaman Blade than the original Raideen and having a Shōjo feel to it.
>   <sub>[Brave Raideen: Raideen the Superior - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brave_Raideen#Raideen_the_Superior)</sub>

Comment: You can use [this link](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge your accounts

Comment: @Edlothiad I think the two accounts work well together. :)